# Error 5123 restaurar BD SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

Me podrían ayudar con este error, cuando trato de adjuntar la bd, selecciono el archivo .mdf y me manda este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe mencionar, que antes si podía adjuntar las bd, pero ahora me sale este error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente, está intentando restaurar la base de datos, en la misma ruta que existe una base de datos activa que puede estar siendo usado por la instancia de sql server o por otra.

Normalmente en las bases de datos de SQL Server.  Se restauran los archivos de extensiòn .bak o .bk.  Ud. está seleccionanado un archivo de extensión MDF que corresponde al archivo primario (de datos) de la base de datos.

El comando para crear una copia es:
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
BACKUP DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
TO DISK = 'Z:\SQLServerBackups\AdventureWorks2012.Bak'
   WITH FORMAT,
      MEDIANAME = 'Z_SQLServerBackups',
      NAME = 'Full Backup of AdventureWorks2012';
GO

El comando para restaurar una copia es 
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
   FROM DISK = 'Z:\SQLServerBackups\AdventureWorks2012.bak'
   WITH       RECOVERY;

Comment: Me parece que yo restaure el .mdf pero luego la elimine. Ahora que quiero volver a restaurar la bd .mdf me manda ese error, que solucion podría tener? PD: No tengo instancias solo la principal

Comment: Bueno , tuve una idea, pase los archivos .mdf y log a otra ubicacion y de alli los llame, siempre y cuando el sql management server este en modo administrador. PD: Es normal que la tabla Data de SQL te restrinja permisos tanto para copiar y pegar?